# Unity Facebook SDK - "FB.API" appears to not save or load score values

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm creating a game for the Facebook Canvas using the official Facebook SDK. Despite using code directly from the Facebook Unity example, I cannot save nor load a score value. I receive no error or message whatsoever - A value of 0 is always returned when I attempt to retrieve the score. Everything else (logging in, posting to the news feed, etc.) is working fine - just not the score management. Also, this occurs both in the Unity editor and on the canvas itself.

I save the player's score like this:

```
public void SaveScore(int _score)
{
    _fbScore = _score;

    var _query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    _query["score"] = _fbScore.ToString();

    FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, delegate(FBResult r) { Util.Log("Result: " + r.Text); }, _query);

    //FB.API ("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, ScoreSaveCallBack, scoreData);
    _hiScoreText.text = _fbScore.ToString();
}
```

I then try to retrieve the score with this method:

```
public void GetHighScore()
{
    if (_fbIsInited)
        FB.API ("/app/scores?fields=score,user.limit(20)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, GetScoreCallBack);
}
```

Callback method:

```
void GetScoreCallBack(FBResult _result)
{
    try 
    {
        List<object> _scoresList = Util.DeserializeScores(_result.Text);
        foreach(object _score in _scoresList)
        {
            var _entry = (Dictionary<string,object>) _score;
            var _user  = (Dictionary<string,object>) _entry["user"];

            string _userId = (string)_user["id"];

            if (string.Equals(_userId, FB.UserId))
            {
                _fbScore = GetScoreFromEntry(_entry);
                _hiScoreText.text = _fbScore.ToString();
                Debug.Log("FB SCORE: + " + _fbScore);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception _e)
    {
        Debug.Log(_e.Message);
    }
}
```

As the score returned is always 0, I do not know whether the problem is with the save or load methods.

EDIT:
To make matters worse, out of nowhere, I've started getting these errors when I attempt to post the score:

```
You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading.
403 Forbidden
UnityEngine.WWW:get_text()
FBResult:get_Text()
FacebookManager:<SaveScore>m__0(FBResult) (at Assets/Scripts/Facebook/FacebookManager.cs:138)
Facebook.<Start>c__Iterator0:MoveNext()
```

I haven't made any changes to the code, they just started appearing every time!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue . have you solved it yes ?

Comment: hey m also facing this problem.. :(((

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you pass a numeric app id in this call instead of 'app'?

```
FB.API ("/123456789/scores?fields=score,user.limit(20)"
```

You can find your's app code at [FacebookDeveloper](https://developers.facebook.com/) dashboard, on your app's main panel - it's the 'application identifier'.

Have you also specified this number in unity Facebook|Facebook Settings|App id? That should fix your problems.